# What is a reasonable way to setup a unit testing environment in Angular with fake back-end?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, test-environments

I have a pretty standard Angular application, which comes with the standard Jasmine + Karma frameworks for unit testing.

In my application I have several services which make use of the `HttpClient` class to query a back-end, and I obviously need to unit test all these services too.

I realized I need to mock the back-end with a local server, which answers to the HTTP queries with hard-coded JSON.

I found many different suggestions on-line, but they don't fit or are too complicated.

What I'd like to have:

- no additional code to be added to the original angular services
- no tricky solutions (like using HTTP Interceptors, etc.)
- no complicated proxy configuration, or definition of specific `npm run` scripts
- easy to write fake DB (e.g. hard-coded JSON file)
- since my real back-end exposes Restful APIs, with standard CRUD operations, I would like to avoid describing each single end-point in the fake back-end
- when I type `ng test` the fake back-end (with a different base URL) should be automatically used

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: I recently found this: mockoon and use it. Give it a try. I think it satisfied áll your reqs.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock your backend by using the [HttpTestingController](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController)
This class allows you to test that certain endpoints are called (and how many times), but also allows you to fake responses through the flush method.

Here's a small snipet where I return a fake response for the localhost/data endpoint, where httpMock is an instance of HttpClientController, defined in beforeEach.

```
const someCall = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost/data').flush('some fake response ');
```

We can then use someCall to also test what data was send to the backend like this if you would like to do that.

```
expect(someCall.request.body.someJSONProperty).toEqual('some value');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a possible solution I followed.

Install `json-server`

```
npm install json-server
```

In a dedicated folder (say `fake-back-end`) in the project root create the server file `server.js`

```
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const server = jsonServer.create();

const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
server.use(middlewares);

const router = jsonServer.router('fake-back-end/db.json');
server.use(router);
server.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Fake-Backend Server is running');
});
```

and the data base `db.json`

```
{
    "models1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "field1": "",
            "field2": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "field1": "",
            "field2": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "field1": "",
            "field2": "",
        },
        ...
    ],
    "models2": [
        ...
    ],
    "models3": [
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

and the routes file `routes.json`

```
{
    "/api/v1/*": "/$1",
    "/api/v1/:resource/:id": "/:resource/:id"
}
```

Create a testing environment file `src/environments/environment.testing.ts` which sets the baseUrl of the fake back-end.

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```

Now the problem is how can I have `ng test` automatically

- launch the json-server with `json-server --watch .\fake-back-end\db.json  --routes .\fake-back-end\routes.json`
- set the testing environment